# linq join question

Tags: c#, linq

Suppose we have two tables like this:

table1

```
|   date   | data1 |
| 3/2/2011 |  xyz  |
| 3/4/2011 |  abc  |
```

table2

```
|  date    |  data2  |  data3  |
| 3/2/2011 |  def    |   ghi   |
| 3/9/2011 |  jkl    |   mno   |
```

How do we write a join to get

`| date | data1  |  data2  |  data3`  |

Let's say we have MyModel defined like this:

```
MyModel{
  public DateTime TheDate {get;set;}
  public int Data1 {get;set;}
  public int Data2 {get;set;}
  public int Data3 {get;set;}
}
```

I know we have to use DefaultIfEmpty but I don't know how to merge the two when there's no corresponding date line like in row 2 of both tables.

Thanks for any ideas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var results = from t1 in table1
              let t2 = (from t in table2 select t)
              where t1.date == t2.date
              select new MyModel {
                TheDate = t1.date == null ? t2.date : t1.date,
                Data1 = t1.data1,
                Data2 = t2.data2,
                Data3 = t2.data3
              };
```

Comment: In the statement where t1.date == t2.date, t2. date doesn't appear in the intellisense.

Comment: I just replace the let statement with a from and it seems to work; at least there are no syntax errors.